# Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-programming

I am setting my my variable like

```
Map<String, Function<CLASS_NAME, Comparable>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

where `Comparable` is giving the warning message as

```
Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized
```

I am using it like

```
map.put(VARIABLE_NAME1, s -> s.getStringProperty());
map.put(VARIABLE_NAME2, s -> s.getIntProperty());
..
```

I am using for compare like

```
Comparator<CLASS_TYPE> v = Comparator.comparing(map.get(VARIABLE_NAME), Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

What type of Generic should be used to avoid the warning?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using the code? That could probably help understand why and what do you need here.

Comment: I really doubt its going to work that way if you are looking for any type to be accommodated with the `Function`. Why don't you store a `Map<String, Comparator<CLASS_NAME>`  itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your current scheme.

1. `Comparator` and `Comparable` are two different approaches to comparing objects. You are confusing the two.
2. You are trying to store a function that does comparisons into the map. Later, you fetch the value from the map and try to compare it (the function) to a `Comparator`. This won't work, as you can't compare a function to anything except another function.
3. You don't actually store a value anywhere; you are only storing a function.
4. In your example, you store two different values to the same `VARIABLE_NAME`. Is that intentional?

If you want to create a property map, then you need to create a storable object that can be stored into the map, and can compare its value to a provided value. For instance,

```
class Storable<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private final T value;
  Storable(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  int compareTo(Object other) {
    if ( value.getClass().equals(other.getClass()) ) {
      return value.compareTo( (T) other );
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Now create appropriate sub-classes:

```
class StorableInt extends Storable<Integer> {
    StorableInt(Integer t) {
        super(t);
    }
}
class StorableString extends Storable<String> {
    StorableString(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Your property map now looks like:

```
Map<String, Storable<?>>map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(variableName1, new StorableInt(13));
map.put(variableName2, new StorableString("string2"));

<T extends Comparable<T>> int compare( String key, T val ) {
  return map.get( key ).compareTo( val );
}
```

You can now store properties into your map and compare values against those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is obviously a generic type.

So all you need is just:

```
Map<String, Function<CLASS_NAME, Comparable<CLASSNAME>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

instead of

```
Map<String, Function<CLASS_NAME, Comparable>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or you want to compare another type..?

```
Map<String, Function<CLASS_NAME, Comparable<SomeOtherClass>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I tried this but `map.put(VARIABLE_NAME, s -> s.getProperty());` gives error as `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Comparable<CLASS_NAME>`

Comment: @ruhewo Ok. Then You should use `Map<String, Function<CLASS_NAME, Object>>` (Guessed with what you've edited)

Comment: After trying with `Object`, I am getting the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>> to Comparator<? super U>` in `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())`. I also tried with `Comparable<?>` but the same error.

Comment: @ruhewo What you want to achieve through those codes? It's not clear